# isSelected() not working for radio buttons in selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

isSelected() always returning false even though radio button is in selected state.

below is my HTML when radio button not selected

```
<input type="radio" class="chkbox" name="time1" value="3">
```

And below is my HTML when radio button selected

```
<input type="radio" class="chkbox" name="time1" value="3" checked> == $0
```

isSelected returning false for both the cases

```
driver.findElement(By.name("time1")).isSelected()
```

Also I had tried with getAttribute("checked") and it is returning null

```
driver.findElement(By.name("time1")).getAttribute("checked")
```

Can someone help me to get radio button selected state!!!

Comment: I have same issue, but I think we can not use this isSelected method here as it return same result every time

Answer (score 0):

I am using following workaround to get radio button selected state for my HTML

```
public boolean isRadioButtonSelected() {
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='time1' and @value='3']")).isDisplayed()) {
            return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='time1' and @value='3' and @checked]")).isDisplayed();
        }
        return false;
    }
```